# set default Cache-Control header for static resources using aiohttp as web server

Tags: python, aiohttp

How to set header `Cache-Control: no-cache` for static files to make the development of `aiohttp` web application more comfortable? I studied for several hours to get this result. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

```py
from aiohttp import web

routes = [
    web.get('/hot-reload', hot_reload),
    web.get('/demo/index', demo.index),
    web.get('/demo/fetch', demo.fetch),
    web.static('/foo', '/foo', name='static1'),
    web.static('/', '/public', name='static2'),
]

@web.middleware
async def cache_control(request: web.Request, handler):
    response: web.Response = await handler(request)
    resource_name = request.match_info.route.name
    if resource_name and resource_name.startswith('static'):
        response.headers.setdefault('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
    return response

app = web.Application(middlewares=[cache_control])
app.add_routes(routes)
```